# Aggregating data with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongodb. My data is as follows. Each document is either of type question or answer. The id field denotes which data point the question and answers belong.

```
{'id':1, 'type':'question','text':'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
{'id':1, 'type':'answer','text':'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
{'id':1, 'type':'answer','text':'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
{'id':1, 'type':'answer','text':'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'}

{'id':2, 'type':'question','text':'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
{'id':2, 'type':'answer','text':'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
{'id':2, 'type':'answer','text':'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'}

...

{'id':3, 'type':'question','text':'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
{'id':3, 'type':'answer','text':'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
{'id':3, 'type':'answer','text':'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
```

I want to aggregate them as following.

```
{'id':1,'question':qtn_txt,'answers':[ans1text, ans2text,...]}
{'id':2,'question':qtn_txt,'answers':[ans1text, ans2text,...]}
{'id':3,'question':qtn_txt,'answers':[ans1text, ans2text,...]}
```

How do I go ahead do that with mongodb aggregate? I tried `$group` with `type` but was not able to distinguish between question and answer to push them into separate arrays.

Comment: your db is not well designed for nosql database, you should initially store your data like: ```{'id':1,'question':qtn_txt,'answers':[ans1text, ans2text,...]}```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Ended up changing the way I store data and started using $lookup to get data in the above format.